# How does the Style.BasedOn Property work internally?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

**Background**

I am developing an application that generates Labels based on data provided in a CSV file. I would like the user to be able to apply Templates to change the appearance of these Labels, I also need the user to be able to Edit and Modify these Templates.

I am deriving these Templates from the Existing Style Class in WPF. Even though I am presenting this to the End user as a 'Template', for the sake of this post, I will refer to them as Styles to avoid confusion with Data Templating.

Due to a Style becoming Sealed after use or after being referenced by another style.BasedOn Property, in order to allow the user to Modify these Styles, for each modification, I need to generate a new Style based on the Current Style. I do this using the BasedOn Property.

**Question**

*What is actually happening internally when the Style.BasedOn property is set and that style is consumed by an element?*

My first thought was that a copy of the Setters collection was created and applied to the new Style, but as the following code shows, that is not the case:

```
 var styleA = new Style();
            styleA.Setters.Add(new Setter(/* DP and Value */));

 var styleB = new Style();
            styleB.BasedOn = styleA;

 Console.WriteLine(styleA.Setters.Count);
 Console.WriteLine(styleB.Setters.Count);

 // Ouput.
 // 1
 // 0
```

My next thought is that the BasedOn property holds a reference to the style applied to it, and the actual logic is performed by the FrameworkElement.Style OnPropertyChanged handler. I had a look through the  Reference Source, but in all honesty, got in over my head pretty quickly.

Any help or suggestions for another way to approach the problem will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested for another approach, here is one commonly used: *resource dictionnaries*.

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="DefaultLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**StyleBlue.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Generic.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultLabelStyle}" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**StyleRed.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Generic.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultLabelStyle}" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Demo**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void SetTheme(string theme)
        {
            var mergedDictionaries = Resources.MergedDictionaries;
            mergedDictionaries.Clear();
            var dictionary = new ResourceDictionary {Source = new Uri(theme)};
            mergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
        }

        private void ButtonRedTheme_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetTheme(@"pack://application:,,,/Themes/StyleRed.xaml");
        }

        private void ButtonBlueTheme_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetTheme(@"pack://application:,,,/Themes/StyleBlue.xaml");
        }
    }
}
```

[image] 
[image]

As you can see in [Style.BasedOn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx), there's simply no indication of what's happening under the hood, certainly ***a lot***.

However, following is said : *Typically, you use the Markup Extensions and WPF 
XAML to refer to an existing style.*

As an end-user it happens that you simply don't have to know the inner workings as there are simpler patterns for using this feature : XAML / resource dictionaries.

There is plenty of documentation for styling/templates, start by reading this one : [Styling and Templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms745683(v=vs.100).aspx)

For your users you could direct them to [XamlPad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398(v=vs.85).aspx) for creating these templates, you'd get real-time preview at the same time.

- versed users will know what to do and will be able to
- for beginners you can provide a *starter pack* of templates

Weigh the 'pros' and 'cons' of this solution against using 'CSV' and 'code' approach (extensible only with your involvement and IMO doomed to fail).

**EDIT**

You can see exactly what's happening in `BasedOn` by looking at the source code : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Style.cs,dd312833d0723042

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although it is important that the End User has a GUI interface in which to Create New or modify existing Styles, I don't want them to have to learn XAML in order to create new Styles.

To this end, as far as I am aware, I need to generate these styles in Code. My question comes from the possible problem of Styles stacking up, and eventuating in one Style that is based on multiple styles before it, in my mind, this could cause Memory leaks over the run time life of the application.